# Как записать меняющийся список в файл python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict

Есть список с ключами словаря внутри `list = [f'game{i}']`, переменная с каждой итерацией увеличивается. Есть цикл

```
for i in range(0, 20)
    list = [game[f'game{i}']]
    with open('tasks.txt', 'x') as file:
        for item in list:
            file.write(item + '\n')
        file.close()
```

Когда я пытаюсь записать таким методом данные в файл. То записывается всего одна строка. А строк там по размеру range т.е. 20. Как записать все 20 строк?

**UPD:** Пока предпологается что в переменную `item`, переходит только 1 раз переменная `game{i}`

Comment: @entithat Есть ли какой нибудь другой путь записать это в файл?

Comment: А нет, я ошибся.

Comment: `with open(..., "a")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно открыть файл на дозапись, т.е. делать так:

```
with open('tasks.txt', 'a') as file:
```

Answer (score 1):

Open надо вынести за for

```
with open...
    for...
```